# Getting bytes of a webpage from selenium

Tags: python, selenium, driver

I am trying to scrape a webpage with a pdf.

With request, I used the following code to get the bytes and save it with open()

```
    pdf_response = requests.get(pdf_url)
    
    with open("sample.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf_response.content)
        f.close
```

And it works just fine,

However on the below webpage I am using selenium but could not get the bytes from response object to use in the above code,

```
#This does not return a byte object as requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(base)

content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

[link to pdf (this has captcha that I solve with 2captcha)](https://www.sedar.com/GetFile.do?lang=EN&docClass=8&issuerNo=00028264&issuerType=03&projectNo=03079934&docId=4755532)

Current response that I recieve

‘‘

Comment: why do you strip it ? It can create wrong data.

Comment: what do you get in `content` ? Maybe you get something different then you expect.

Comment: As I run page manually in browser and solve captcha then it opens window to select folder for saving file - it doesn't need to get content and save it manually. And probably using Chrome `Options()` you can set default folder so it will save it automatically without asking for folder.

Comment: Hi furas, Thanks for your inputs. 
However, I am still not able to resolve this thing. Is it possible for you to contact me at hggoyal06@gmail.com or provide your email for me to contact you

Comment: I can't help you - I used Google to find more information and I found ie. [How to save as PDF on Chrome using Selenium](https://www.edureka.co/community/40584/how-to-save-as-pdf-on-chrome-using-selenium) and [Selenium Webdriver - browser preferences for downloading files](https://blog.j-labs.pl/2017/02/Selenium-Webdriver-browser-preferences-for-downloading-files). It shows how to change settings to save PDF in selected folder instead of asking of folder, and instead of displaying preview in browser.

Comment: I tried all those, but nothing seems to be working, Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: maybe first check what you get in `content` - maybe there are useful information which helps you understand what you get - if browser uses some PDF viewer then you can get this viewer code instead of PDF.

Comment: OR maybe you should use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox to analyze requests send from browser to server. As I see it sends POST requests with captcha code - and you could use this information to do the same with `requests.post()`

Comment: It fetches a very short html, with embed name tag

When I use Requests, it pull the whole byte code of the page which can then be written with open()

Comment: you should show all information which you get - now you only wasted time waitng for help.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for that,

`<html><head></head><body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(82, 86, 89);"><embed name="902E0DE5CAA212DF6C98D7DE8EF12129" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="902E0DE5CAA212DF6C98D7DE8EF12129"></body></html>`

Comment: you should add all information in question, not in comment -  it will be more readable and more people will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get PDF using only `requests`

Only problem: I use `pillow` to generate image with full code and display it, and I have to manually recognize this code. But if you have some method to recognize it automatically then it is not problem.

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from PIL import Image
import io

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
}

# --- create Session ---

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

# --- load main page ---

url = 'https://www.sedar.com/GetFile.do?lang=EN&docClass=8&issuerNo=00028264&issuerType=03&projectNo=03079934&docId=4755532'  # JSON

r = s.get(url)

# --- get images ---

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)

image_urls = soup.xpath('//img/@src')

# --- generate one image ---

full_image = Image.new('RGB', (40*5, 50))

for i, url in enumerate(image_urls):
    #print(url)
    r = s.get('https://www.sedar.com/' + url)
    
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))
    
    full_image.paste(image, (40*i, 0))

# --- ask for code --- 

full_image.show()

code = input('code> ')

#print('code:', code)

# --- get PDF ---

r = s.post('https://www.sedar.com/CheckCode.do', data={'code': code})

if r.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/pdf':
    print('It is not PDF file')
else:
    with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as fh:
        print('size:', fh.write(r.content))
```

Comment: hey Furas, Thanks for this

It will indeed help me to improve my code to join those 5 captcha images.

However, the issue still remains the same
It results in a pdf with no result, and error "Failed to load the document"

I wonder, is there a way to get the pdf from the server using embed name

Comment: I have incorporated 2captcha api that identifies the code. Does this post call with code works for you and does the pdf opens at your end?

Comment: this code give me correct PDF. if you get wrong file then maybe server know your IP and it blocks you as a bot. OR you send wrong code. If I use wrong code then I gets HTML with new CODE and it save this HTML.

Comment: BTW: I added `r.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/pdf'` to check if server sends `PDF`

Comment: BTW: you can't get PDF even using embed name if you send wrong code or you use wrong headers (`User-Agent` has to be full value from real browser - it doesn't work with short `Mozilla/5.0`) or you forgot to send cookies (and this is why I use `requests.Session()`)